Probability: continuity and weak topology
Say we have $H : X \rightarrow Y$ which is continuous map between complete separable metric spaces. Then $H_{*}: \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is also continuous (wrt the weak topology), where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$.
How did we get this? I guess we start by looking at the preimage of some bounded continuous function on $\mathcal{P}(Y)$.
My lecturer started saying to look at the preimage of the set of $\mu$ for which the linear functional $\mu \rightarrow \int_{X}{\varphi(x)\mu(dx)}$ is less than 1 under H*.
I think I'm misunderstanding the concepts.


The mapping $H_*$. Let $\mu\in {\cal P}(X)$. Then $\mu \circ H^{-1} \in {\cal P}(Y)$. The mapping $\mu \to \mu \circ H^{-1}$ is the mapping $H^*$. Observe (the standard way: first proving for indicators, and then approximation by simple functions)

$$(*)\quad \int g d (H_*\mu)  = \int (g\circ H) d \mu.$$

The weak-$*$ topology on  ${\cal P}(X)$ is the one making the mappings $\mu \to \int f d \mu$ continuous for every $f \in C_b(X)$: the smallest topology under which the pre-image of every open ball in ${\mathbb R}$ under each of these mappings is an open set.Therefore every open set in this topology is a union of sets of the form $U_{f,x,\epsilon}=\{\mu \in{\cal P}(X): |\int f d\mu - x |<\epsilon\}$, where $f \in C_b(X),x \in {\mathbb R},\epsilon>0$. The weak-$*$ topology on ${\cal }(Y)$ is defined analogously.
Continuity of $H_*$. Let $V_{g,x,\epsilon}$ be an open set in ${\cal P}(Y)$ of the type described in item 2 above. It is enough to show that $H_*^{-1} (V_{g,x,\epsilon})$ is open in ${\cal P}(X)$. Now $\mu\in H_*^{-1} (V_{g,x,\epsilon})$ if and only if  $H_*(\mu) \in V_{g,x,\epsilon}$ if and only if

$$ |\int g d (H_* \mu)- x | <\epsilon,$$
and by $(*)$ this holds if and only if
$$ |\int g\circ H d\mu - x |<\epsilon,$$
That is $\mu \in U_{g\circ H,x,\epsilon}$.
